# Yoast SEO Multilingual конфликтует с WPML?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, yoast, wpml

Есть сайт на `wordpress` c установленными и активированными плагинами [Yoast SEO Premium](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/)
[Yoast SEO Multilingual](https://yoast.com/tag/multilingual-seo/) [WPML Multilingual CMS](https://wpml.org/purchase/). Все официальное, зарегистрировано, активировано.

На локальном сервере **OpenServer c PHP 7.4 и Apache** все между собой в связке работает отлично, а вот при переносе на реальный под управлением **Nginx docker c PHP 7.4** получаю фатальную ошибку.

> NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  include(/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wp-seo-multilingual/vendor/composer/../../classes/Utils.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

> NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wp-seo-multilingual/vendor/composer/../../classes/Utils.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

> NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'WPML\WPSEO\Utils' not found in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wp-seo-multilingual/classes/class-wpml-wpseo-should-create-redirect.php:29

**Stack trace:**

> #0 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/classes/action-filter-loader/class-wpml-action-filter-loader.php(154): WPML_WPSEO_Should_Create_Redirect->add_hooks()

> #1 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/classes/action-filter-loader/class-wpml-action-filter-loader.php(92): WPML_Action_Filter_Loader->run_factory(Object(WPML_WPSEO_Main_Factory))

> #2 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/classes/action-filter-loader/class-wpml-action-filter-loader.php(76): WPML_Action_Filter_Loader->load_factory(Object(WPML_WPSEO_Main_Factory))

> #3 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/classes/action-filter-loader/class-wpml-action-filter-loader.php(45): WPML_Action_Filter_Loader->load_factory_or_action('WPML_WPSEO_Main...', false)

> #4 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wp-seo-mu in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wp-seo-multilingual/classes/class-wpml-wpseo-should-create-redirect.php on line 29

> "GET /index.php" 500

Если деактивирую `Yoast SEO Multilingual` то сайт уже работает. В чем причина и как можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по стектрейсу, предыдущая версия в папке wp-seo-multilingual/classes/ называлась "utils.php" (в нижнем регистре), а сейчас в верхнем регистре - и это может не детектиться в гит как изменение и в некоторых операционных системах может не считаться за разные имена.

Поэтому:

- переименуйте файл utils.php в какое-нибудь другое наименование (например в utilsx.php
- переименуйте его в Utils.php

Если вы используете git то после каждого переименования коммитьте изменения.

Answer (score 1):

У вас, возможно, старая версия плагина Yoast SEO Multilingual, в ней нет файла classes/Utils.php. Скачайте последнюю - 1.1.1.

Comment: ах если бы! У меня все плагины последних версий, Yoast SEO Multilingual 1.2.0 и там есть файл classes/utils.php ...

Comment: Возможно, что-то с правами на файл

Comment: помог дайнгрейд с Yoast SEO Multilingual 1.2.0 до 1.1.1, но сама причина так и не ясна

Comment: В поддержку, значит, надо писать. Похоже на баг.